# Google analytics v4 and google API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-authentication

Is possible to use Google API to fetch data for a Google Analytics 4 property?

If yes, is there a way to authorize users and access data from their accounts and properties (like the Embed API js working)?

I will create that APP using PHP and the PHP package https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there aren't API available for GA4 Property. You have to use BigQuery to get data.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what I thought. With BigQuery can I create an app accessing multiple accounts ?

Comment: I would say it depends on the sharing settings